# Python window opens and closes

Tags: python, pygame

I've been following a tutorial from [here](https://pythonprogramming.net/pygame-tutorial-moving-images-key-input/?completed=/displaying-images-pygame/) to build a small python game.
This would be the code behind it:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

display_width = 1280
display_height = 720

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Racing Game")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
carImg = pygame.image.load("racecar.png")

def car(x,y):
    gameDisplay.blit(carImg, (x,y))

x = display_width * 0.45
y = display_height * 0.8
x_change = 0
car_speed = 0

crashed = True
while crashed:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            crashed = False
        ## <code to remove>
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x_change = -5
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_change = 5
        if event.type = pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_change = 0
        ## </code to remove>
        print(event)
    x += x_change
    gameDisplay.fill((255,255,255))
    car(x,y)
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.display.quit()   
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

When I try to run it the window opens and immediately closes. If I remove however the code between the two `## <code to remove>` and `## </code to remove>` everything works fine. What is causing in that piece of code for this to happen?

Comment: This doesn't compile (invalid syntax): `if event.type = pygame.KEYUP:`.

Comment: Works fine with me. Note I fixed the problem stated by @ggorlen. FYI: I am using Raspbian Stretch w/ Python 3.5

Comment: Caused by the invalid syntax error. Next time try running it through the terminal (or command line on Windows) instead to see the actual error code

Comment: @Gabriel Python scans for syntax before starting the interpreter, so this is pre-runtime entirely.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by the syntax error at `if event.type = pygame.KEYUP:`. Opening the file will cause it to close instantly, but running it in the interpreter (IDLE) will show you that error. Just change it to `if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:` and everything will work fine.

**UPDATE:**

Running code from the file rather than the interpreter (IDLE) won't always open. It is best to run it in IDLE.

Code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

display_width = 1280
display_height = 720

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Racing Game")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
carImg = pygame.image.load("racecar.png")

def car(x,y):
    gameDisplay.blit(carImg, (x,y))

x = display_width * 0.45
y = display_height * 0.8
x_change = 0
car_speed = 0

crashed = True
while crashed:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            crashed = False
        #############################
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x_change = -5
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_change = 5
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_change = 0
        #############################
        print(event)
    x += x_change
    gameDisplay.fill((255,255,255))
    car(x,y)
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.display.quit()   
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: If you found this answer to be the solution, don't forget to accept it.

Comment: @GhostCat This was a mistake. Thank you for letting me know. I meant to put "Unsalvageable".